# Vue.js/JSX: Dynamic event name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs-jsx

I am writing a Vue.js component. The component renders an `<input>`
element. An event listener is listening to either `change` or `input`
event, according to the value of a prop.

How to write the render function with JSX?

```
{
  props: {
    lazy: Boolean,
  },
  render(h) {
    const bindEvent = this.lazy? 'change' : 'input'
    return h('input', {
      attrs: {
        type: 'text',
      },
      on: {
        [bindEvent]: e => this.$emit('update', e.target.value)
      },
    })
  },
}
```

I want to write something like this:

```
render(h) {
  const bindEvent = this.lazy? 'change' : 'input'
  return <input
    type='text'
    on={{ [bindEvent]: e => this.$emit('update', e.target.value) }}
  />
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Adding event listener to each event

```
render(h) {
  const eventHandler = name =>
    (this.bindEvent === name)? e => this.$emit('update', e.target.value)
    : () => {}
  return <input
    type='text'
    onChange={eventHandler('change')}
    onInput={eventHandler('input')}
  />
}
```

#### Solution 2: Adding event listener to VNode

```
render(h) {
  const eventHandler = name =>
    (this.bindEvent === name)? e => this.$emit('update', e.target.value)
    : () => {}
  const vNode= <input type='text' />
  vNode.data.on = { [this.bindEvent]: e => this.$emit('update', e.target.value) }
  return vNode
}
```

Comment: The solution 2 is exactly what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Just a little tweak, like this.

```
<input
  type="text"
  v-on="{ [bindEvent]: e => this.$emit('update', e.target.value) }"
/>
```

See [working implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/43jqxkk8kx).

Comment: Sure, that works for templates but not for JSX in render function. It compiles to `"directives": [{ name: "on", value: { [this.bindEvent]: e => { this.bindValue(e.target.value); } } }]`. And the console: `[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: on`